# apache2 suexec destroy my day

Tags: debian, apache2, suexec

I have a puzzle with http suEXEC now.
It is a bit of frustration. Basically apache2 report weird lines in error.log

```
[Fri Dec 18 11:29:57.385776 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 10944] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.38 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.38, Library: OpenSSL/1.1.1d
[Fri Dec 18 11:29:57.385847 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 10944] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)


[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3873 10949/7fc39bfff700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3873 10954/7f5afc99e700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:422 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3873 10949/7fc3a8fba980 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:901 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3873 10954/7f5afca9d980 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:492 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3874 10954/7f5afc99e700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3874 10954/7f5aeffff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3874 10954/7f5aeffff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3875 10949/7fc39b7fe700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3875 10949/7fc39b7fe700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3876 10949/7fc39affd700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.3] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3876 10949/7fc39affd700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.3] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3877 10949/7fc39a7fc700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.4] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3877 10949/7fc39a7fc700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.4] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3878 10949/7fc39bfff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3878 10949/7fc39bfff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3879 10949/7fc399ffb700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2020-12-18 11:29:57.3879 10949/7fc399ffb700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
```

And the starting sequence looks OK, however occasionally whatever suexec plays a role it doesn't load properly.
How can i trace it, or find it.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
a2dismod passanger
```

does the trick

Comment: A bit more explanation on *why* this is the solution wouldn't hurt.